# Photoshop script - get word from external file

Tags: javascript, replace, find, photoshop

The script below is recorded with Photoshop's script listner. It searches the document for the word "Sun" and replaces it with the word "Moon".

My question: how to get the replacement word, "Moon", from an external .txt file?

```
// =======================================================
var id1 = charIDToTypeID( "Opn " );
var desc1 = new ActionDescriptor();
var id2 = charIDToTypeID( "null" );
desc1.putPath( id2, new File( "C:\\document.psd" ) );
executeAction( id1, desc1, DialogModes.NO );

// =======================================================
var id3 = stringIDToTypeID( "replace" );
var desc2 = new ActionDescriptor();
var id4 = charIDToTypeID( "null" );
    var ref1 = new ActionReference();
    var id5 = charIDToTypeID( "Prpr" );
    var id6 = stringIDToTypeID( "replace" );
    ref1.putProperty( id5, id6 );
    var id7 = charIDToTypeID( "TxLr" );
    var id8 = charIDToTypeID( "Ordn" );
    var id9 = charIDToTypeID( "Al  " );
    ref1.putEnumerated( id7, id8, id9 );
desc2.putReference( id4, ref1 );
var id10 = charIDToTypeID( "Usng" );
    var desc3 = new ActionDescriptor();
    var id11 = stringIDToTypeID( "find" );
    desc3.putString( id11, "Sun" );
    var id12 = stringIDToTypeID( "replace" );
    desc3.putString( id12, "Moon" );
    var id13 = stringIDToTypeID( "checkAll" );
    desc3.putBoolean( id13, true );
    var id14 = charIDToTypeID( "Fwd " );
    desc3.putBoolean( id14, false );
    var id15 = stringIDToTypeID( "caseSensitive" );
    desc3.putBoolean( id15, true );
    var id16 = stringIDToTypeID( "wholeWord" );
    desc3.putBoolean( id16, false );
   var id17 = stringIDToTypeID( "findReplace" );
   desc2.putObject( id10, id17, desc3 );
    executeAction( id3, desc2, DialogModes.NO );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out my answer on this question.  [How does one load some variables at runtime in Photoshop Script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21767554/how-does-one-load-some-variables-at-runtime-in-photoshop-script).  If the word you are after is the only word in your document then, the variable 'str' will contain your word. Also check out my answer here: [Find and replace text in multiple Photoshop files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20476728/find-and-replace-text-in-multiple-photoshop-files) which provides a find/replace method that doesn't rely on the messy script listener code.

At minimum add the following to the top of the code you've provided:

```
var file = new File( /c/folder/yourfile.txt );       
file.open("r");
var str = file.read();
```

Then replace the line

```
desc3.putString( id12, "Moon" );
```

with

```
desc3.putString( id12, str );
```

If that doesn't work you'll need to post your updated code so I can see what you are doing wrong.

Comment: Thank you for your reply and your time! Unfortunatley, I just don't have the skills to make it work. After much guesswork, no result. It's clear for me that I should work on this part: desc3.putString( id12, "Moon" );. And add some file.open("r"); and file.read();. Tried diffrent variations, no luck...

Comment: Thank you! It worked great! One more question: if the external text file contains several paragraphs, not just one word, the script gets all the text but completely ignores paragraph breaks (the blank line between paragraphs). I realize that because the script uses Photoshop's built in search/replace function it may have limitations. However, is there any way to make it import the paragraph breaks?